# Is it possible to update db from web-page in Django?

Tags: django

There is a django-site with models and db.
It is possible to update/add to the db info from my models like

```
a = Model()
a.name = 'name'
a.save()
```

directly form site page, but not througth admin page?

Comment: Admin pages are not "magical", this is in fact a Django app, so yes. Some Django developers even give users access to django-admin pages, to update objects.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

it is a very bad idea to allow users that are not staff use your admin.
You need to create function in your views.py file in which you will create or update your models.

something like:

```
def my_function(request):
    name = request.POST.get('name')
    a = Model()
    a.name = name
    a.save()
    return a
```